# Cleaned data from formset

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I access form claned_data ​​in frame sets in **forms.py**?
I want for example get amount value that user entered and calculate

Comment: Please show your code, are you talking about cleaning the data from all forms in a formset? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation

Comment: I build functions for validation a lot of the time, starting off with the following in the function: `cleaned_data = super(form_type, form).clean()`. Then I can run `cleaned_data.get('field_name')` to pull the cleaned data validate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i had to change my senario